# how to save the test snapshots in xcode7 UITesting when ran using xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, jenkins, ui-testing

I am running xcode7 ui tests via jenkins, and would like to have a screenshot of the failures.

I know how to do it via xcode itself:

[image: screenshot functionality on xcode]

The question is how to do it when tests are ran via xcodebuild

```
xcodebuild -workspace bla.xcworkspace test
```

Answer (score 1):

defining the `-derivedDataPath` flag on `xcodebuild` will save all the test data. the screenshots specifically, can be found under `Logs/Test/Attachments/` in wherever you save the derivedData